# bootstrap datepicker not working in safari iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a bootstarp datepicker . and works good in desktop. but it is not working in mobile safari. what should i do to working correctly in safari?

```
<html><head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.worldinbag.com/js/Pediaa.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.worldinbag.com/js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
    .datePicker,.datePickerControl{position:relative;display:inline-block;width:100%}.datePickerMonthName{display:none}.datePickerPopup *{text-align:center!important;right:0 !important;}.datePickerYear{float:left;display:block;width:102px;margin:0 2px}.datePickerMonth{float:right;display:block;width:102px;margin:0 2px}.datePickerSide{float:left}.datePickerInput input[type=text]{cursor:pointer;text-align:center}.datePickerPage{clear:both;margin:0 -5px}.datePickerPageMonth ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0}.datePickerPageMonth{list-style-type:none;display:block; float:left;margin:0 5px;padding:0}.datePickerWeekDays{display:block;clear:both}.datePickerWeekDays li,.datePickerWeekDaysTitle{float:left;width:30px;height:30px;min-height:30px;padding-top:5px;text-align:center;box-sizing:border-box}.datePickerWeekDays li{color:#333;cursor:pointer;font-size:13px;line-height:21px;border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6}.datePickerPageMonth li.datePickerWeekDays > ul > li{border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6}.datePickerPageMonth li.datePickerWeekDays ~ li.datePickerWeekDays > ul > li{border-top:none}.datePickerPageMonth li.datePickerWeekDays > ul > li:first-child{border-left:1px solid #e6e6e6}.datePickerWeekDaysTitle{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #f2f2f2;color:#000;font-weight:700;font-size:13px}.datePickerWeekDays li.datePickerDisabledDay{color:#DEDEDE}.datePickerEnabledDay:hover{transition:all .1s ease 0;font-weight:700;color:#FFF}.datePickerFrom .datePickerEnabledDay:hover{background:#A7E6FF!important}.datePickerTo .datePickerEnabledDay:hover{background:#A7E6FF!important}.datePickerCurrentDay{background:#fff;color:#000}.datePickerSelectedDay{background:#FC0;color:#FFF!important;font-weight:700}.datePickerFrom .datePickerSelectedDay{background:#FC0!important}.datePickerTo .datePickerSelectedDay{background:#00658d!important}.datePickerPairFrom{background:#00658d!important;color:#fff!important;font-weight:700}.datePickerPairTo{background:#FC0!important;color:#fff!important;font-weight:700}.datePickerNext,.datePickerPrev{cursor:pointer;opacity:.7;background:#fff;font-weight:700;color:#000;height:35px;width:35px;position:relative}.datePickerNext:before,.datePickerPrev:before{font-size:0px;margin:0 auto;position:absolute;line-height:35px!important;display:block!important;right:0;left:0}.datePickerMonthName{display:none}.datePickerNext,.datePickerMonthRight{float:right;width:16px; height:16px;}.datePickerPrev{float:left;width:16px;height:16px;}.datePickerMonthLeft,.datePickerMonthRight{padding:10px 0;padding-top:0; margin:0 auto;width:128px;text-align:center;font-size:13px}.datePickerNavigate{display:inline-block;width:100%;margin-bottom:5px}.datePickerCalendarSwitch{display:block;margin:0 3px 10px}.datePickerPopupDouble .datePickerCalendarSwitch{margin:6px auto 0!important}.datePickerCalendarSwitch .switchHand{font-size:10px;width:60px!important}.datePickerCalendarSwitch .switchOnValue,.datePickerCalendarSwitch .switchOffValue{padding:0!important;width:40px!important}.datePickerMonthRight{display:none;}.datePickerhsh input{direction:rtl!important;float:right;color:#636363;}.datePickergrg input{direction:ltr!important; float:right;}.datePickerSelectCalendar .datePicker{display:none!important}.singleDp .datePickerPopup .datePickerSelects select{height:27px;margin-top:10px!important;font-size:13px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}.singleDp .datePickerPopup .switch{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}.singleDp .datePickerPopup .datePickerPageMonth:first-child{border-right:none;padding-right:0}.singleDp .datePickerPopup .datePickerWeekDays li,.singleDp .datePickerPopup .datePickerWeekDaysTitle{min-width:35px}.singleDp .datePickerPopup{width:269px}.datePickerPopup{position:absolute;background:#FFF;color:#555;display:none;z-index:10000;font-size:12px;padding:10px;line-height:normal;font-weight:400;border:2px solid rgb(226,82,73);margin-top:7px;overflow:visible;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;width:255px;top:46px !important;right:0px !important;}.datePickerWeekDaysTitle{background-color:transparent;color:#aaa}.datePickerPageMonth:first-child{padding-right:0px !important;border:1px solid #e3e3e3; margin-left:15px!important;}.datePickerPageMonth:last-child{display:none;}.datePickerNext:hover,.datePickerPrev:hover{background-color:#eee}.datePickerEnabledDay:hover,.datePickerFrom .datePickerEnabledDay:hover,.datePickerTo .datePickerEnabledDay:hover{background-color:rgb(226,82,73)!important;}.datePickerSelectedDay,.datePickerFrom .datePickerSelectedDay,.datePickerTo .datePickerSelectedDay,.datePickerPairFrom,.datePickerPairTo{background-color:rgb(226,82,73)!important;}.datePickerRange,.datePickerRangeHover{background-color:#efefef}.datePickerIcon{top:0;right:15px;display:block;position:absolute}.datePickerIcon:before,.datePickerIcon:after{content:"";position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border-style:solid;border-color:transparent;border-top:0}.datePickerIcon:before{bottom:0;right:0;border-bottom-color:rgb(226,82,73);border-width:16px}.datePickerIcon:after{bottom:0;border-bottom-color:#fff;border-width:12px;right:4px}.switch{height:22px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer}.switch,.switch *{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.switch[disabled=disabled]{opacity:.5}.switchKey{height:inherit;position:absolute;top:0;white-space:nowrap}.switchHand{float:left;min-width:20px;padding:3px 5px;position:relative;background:#efefef;border:1px solid #ccc}.switchHand:hover{background:#e4e4e4}.switchOnValue,.switchOffValue,.switchHand{height:inherit;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;float:left;box-sizing:border-box}.switchOnValue,.switchOffValue{padding:0 5px;min-width:25px;margin:0}.switchOnHand .switchOnValue,.switchOnHand .switchOffValue{background:rgb(226,82,73)}.switchOnValue{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #ED8323;box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);text-shadow:1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);padding-right:10px;margin-right:-10px}.switchOffValue{background:#ed8323;box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);text-shadow:0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);padding-left:10px;margin-left:-10px}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="Departure" id="SearchDepDatetop"  placeholder="date" class="es-input2">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        SetPrimaryFunctions();
        function SetPrimaryFunctions() {
        SetDatePickers();
        }
        function SetDatePickers() {
        var $From = $('#SearchDepDatetop').datePicker({
        toleranceUp: 3,
        toleranceDown: 0,
        double: true,
        popupPosition: 'right',
        spaceDays: 0,
        startFrom: new Date()
        })
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if you will like to tell us what exactly is not working we may help you

Comment: the datepicker is not working in safari like other datepickers. in safari when a datepicker click the it opens bottom of page to selecting the date.  but this code is not working like them

Comment: is the plugin compatible with safari mobile ?

Comment: yes it is compatible.

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation of this plugin?

Comment: http://www.worldinbag.com/%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%A7

Comment: do you know what a plugin documentation is?, in the site that you provided why aren't you using the responsive meta tag ?

Comment: it is bootstrap datepicker. i've added responsive meta tag but not change style of showing in mobile

Comment: "bootstrap datepicker" which one ? there are multiple plugins named this way

Comment: i took this datepicker from a site. and i don't know where the code comes from. but in that website this datepicker working correctly in mobile